# How can I access the interim model created by CBOW of gensim Word2Vec?

Tags: python, word2vec, gensim

The gensim Word2Vec allows us to train a model using text. As far as I know, it creates an interim **nx|V|** (**n** is number of relevant concepts, **V** is Vector size, user specified) matrix that stores the information which is later used to create the wordspace. How to access and work with this particular data structure?

Comment: What do you mean by "relevant concepts"?

Comment: Your question is too vague to know what you're really looking for - but in general, if you need the internals of a model, you need to consult the source code – in this case, of gensim's `Word2Vec` class. At the very least, that will help you sharpen your terminology to ask the question you really intend.